# Create a csv from an xquery

Tags: xml, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper, xquery

I am trying to create 2 relational database tables for the below xml via xquery.
I have created one table for the course listing as follows. Which formats perfectly for what I need but when I try and create the section listing, it doesn't seem to create the csv file correctly. The columns the data is exported in doesn't follow each component and I am usure why this is.

This is the undesired output [image]

```
    file:write("course.csv",
    for $x in doc("uwm.xml")//course_listing
    let $y := string-join($x/*[not(name()="section_listing")],"zzcommazz")
    let $y := concat($y,"&#xa;")
    let $y := replace($y,'zzcommazz', ',')
    let $y := replace($y,'"', '&quot;')
    return $y
    )


file:write("section.csv",
for $x in doc("uwm.xml")//section_listing
let $y := string-join($x/*[not(name()="course_listing")],"zzcommazz")
let $y := concat($y,"&#xa;")
let $y := replace($y,'zzcommazz', ',')
let $y := replace($y,'"', '&quot;')
return $y
)


  <?xml version='1.0' ?>
            <root>
            <course_listing>
              <note>#</note>
              <course>216-088</course>
              <title>NEW STUDENT ORIENTATION</title>
              <credits>0</credits>
              <level>U</level>
              <restrictions>; ; REQUIRED OF ALL NEW STUDENTS. PREREQ: NONE</restrictions>
               <section_listing>
                  <section_note></section_note>
                  <section>Se 001</section>
                  <days>W</days>
                  <hours>
                      <start>1:30pm</start>
                      <end></end>
                  </hours>
                  <bldg_and_rm>
                      <bldg>BUS</bldg>
                      <rm>S230</rm>
                  </bldg_and_rm>
                  <instructor>Gusavac</instructor>
                  <comments>9 WKS BEGINNING WEDNESDAY, 9/6/00 </comments>
               </section_listing>
               <section_listing>
                  <section_note></section_note>
                  <section>Se 002</section>
                  <days>F</days>
                  <hours>
                      <start>11:30am</start>
                      <end></end>
                  </hours>
                  <bldg_and_rm>
                      <bldg>BUS</bldg>
                      <rm>S171</rm>
                  </bldg_and_rm>
                  <instructor>Gusavac</instructor>
                  <comments>9 WKS BEGINNING FRIDAY, 9/8/00 </comments>
               </section_listing>
            </course_listing>
            
            <course_listing>
              <note>#</note>
              <course>216-293</course>
              <title>BUSINESS ETHICS</title>
              <credits>3</credits>
              <level>U</level>
              <restrictions>; ; PREREQ: NONE</restrictions>
               <section_listing>
                  <section_note></section_note>
                  <section>Se 001</section>
                  <days>R</days>
                  <hours>
                      <start>2:30pm</start>
                      <end>5:10pm</end>
                  </hours>
                  <bldg_and_rm>
                      <bldg>BUS</bldg>
                      <rm>S230</rm>
                  </bldg_and_rm>
                  <instructor>Silberg</instructor>
               </section_listing>
            </course_listing>
            </root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't followed this in detail and you don't actually say what output you are getting and what output you want, but this is obviously wrong:

```
replace($y,'"', '&quot;')
```

because it replaces a character by itself: '"' and '"' are two different ways of writing the same thing. If you want to write out '"' as 6 characters, you need '&quot;'; but I'm not sure why you would want to do that, since '"' is only meaningful in XML, not in CSV.

Comment: Hi Michael, the error I get is the output to csv on line 75 the exported data doesn't follow the desired structure.
There should be 6 columns but on the 75th row it goes a bit out of whack. I'll post it in the actual question.

Comment: You're not showing us the CSV output, you're showing the result of loading the CSV output into some (unspecified) spreadsheet software. First thing to do is to examine the actual CSV.

Comment: Looking at the csv in notepad++ was a great suggestion. This has resolved my issues as well as some oracle youtubes. Thank you